# How do you allow very large files to have time to upload to firebase before iOS terminates the task?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I have a video sharing app, and when you save a video to firebase storage it works perfectly for videos that are roughly 1 minute or shorter.

The problem that I am having, is when I try to post a longer video (1 min or greater) it never saves to firebase.

The only thing that I can think of is this error that I am getting, and this error only shows up about 30 seconds after I click the save button:

> [BackgroundTask] Background Task 101 ("GTMSessionFetcher-firebasestorage.googleapis.com"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.

Here is my code to save the video to firebase.

```
func saveMovie(path: String, file: String, url: URL) {
    var backgroundTaskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
    // Perform the task on a background queue.
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // Request the task asseration and save the ID
        backgroundTaskID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "Finish doing this task", expirationHandler: {
            // End the task if time expires
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskID!)
            backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
        })
        // Send the data synchronously
        do {
            let movieData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.storage.child(path).child("\(file).m4v").putData(movieData)
        } catch let error {
            fatalError("Error saving movie in saveMovie func. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        //End the task assertion
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskID!)
        backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can allow my video time to upload?

Comment: I don't see how Firebase Storage is involved in your code.

Comment: @ElTomato "firebasestorage.googleapis.com" and "`storage.child(path).child("\(file).m4v").putData(movieData)`" both point to Firebase Storage.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay, thanks.  But where does a guy named 'storage' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato Sorry I made my functions kind of confusing cause i'm a newbie. But storage is just a variable at the top that equals `Storage.storage().reference()`

Comment: Why are you doing this `DispatchQueue.global().async` as Firebase functions are asynchronous. But then you have this `// Send the data synchronously` but again, Firebase functions are *asynchronous*. Last question: Since you know the file path, why cast to Data when  you can just [Upload The File](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) directly with `.putFile`? Oh - for your UI, you can [Monitor Progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress) for progress bar if needed

Comment: @Jay thanks for your response that was super helpful! I have updated my question and I am now wondering if you have any idea how to solve the new problem I am having? Thanks again Jay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out after a long time...

All you have to do is use `.putFile("FileURL")` instead of `.putdata("Data")`. Firebase documentation says you should use `putFile()` instead of `putData()` when uploading large files.

But the hard part is for some reason you can't directly upload the movie URL that you get from the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` function and firebase will just give you an error. So what I did instead was get the data of the movie, save the movie data to a path in the file manager, and use the file manager path URL to upload directly to firebase which worked for me.

```
            //Save movie to Firestore
        do {
            // Convert movie to Data.
            let movieData = try Data(contentsOf: movie)
            // Get path so we can save movieData into fileManager and upload to firebase because movie URL does not work, but fileManager url does work.
            guard let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent(postId!) else { print("Error saving to file manager in addPost func"); return }
            do {
                try movieData.write(to: path)
                // Save the file manager url file to firebase storage
                Storage.storage().reference().child("Videos").child("\(postId!).m4v").putFile(from: path, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("There was an error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Video successfully uploaded.")
                    }
                    // Delete video from filemanager because it would take up too much space to save all videos to file manager.
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path.path)
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error deleting from file manager in addPost func \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("Error writing movieData to firebase \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("There was an error adding video in addPost func \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```